# Required mysql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Required max(date) wise qty according the group by code.

e.g. `Code = 351703105039097`, its `max(date)=20-09-2018`, `Qty=0`. HOwever the result is showing `Qty=1`. Please help me

```
Code              Date     Qty
351701103365043 19-09-2018  1
351703105039097 20-09-2018  0
351703105039097 19-09-2018  1
351703105039139 19-09-2018  1
351703105039139 19-09-2018  0
351703105039303 19-09-2018  1
351703105039915 28-09-2018  0
351703105039915 19-09-2018  1
```

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow!!! In order to get your a better answer, and your answer don't get deleted later on, you would have to read and follow some basic rules and conventions that will help everyone to communicate and help better. Please go to https://stackoverflow.com/help and read about the topic "What topics can I ask about here?", and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?".

Comment: Please publish the code you have tried.

Comment: I see that 351703105039139 has 2 entries for 19-09-2018  do you have some way of deciding which to choose?

Answer (score 0):

You may just use order by DESC to get the details about the latest order.

```
select code, date, qty
from table_name
group by code
order by date DESC;
```

Comment: I agree that this gives the expected result for the data provide but it's not reliable and not the way to use group by. You should test this by swapping the order in which the rows appear for 351703105039097 - in which case the row for the 19-09-2018 is selected. This is consistent with non-determenistic values being returned for date and qty by the group by statement. please refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery :

```
select t.*
from table t
where date = (select max(t1.date)
              from table t1
              where t1.code = t.code
             );
```